# Libgdx Input don't working on Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm new in Libgdx and I'm trying to make a map that can be explored using Camera. Fo that I implements `GestureListener` in my own `Map` class.

```
public class Map extends Stage implements GestureListener {

    public String mapName;
    private Sprite background;
    public LocationPoint points[];
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Batch batch;
    public Music anbientSound;
    public int numOfPoints;
    public int locationsX[];
    public int locationsY[];


    public Map(Sprite background) {
        this.background = background;
    }


    public Sprite getBackground() {
        return background;
    }


    public void activate() {

        InputMultiplexer inputChain = new InputMultiplexer();

        if(points==null) {
            points = new LocationPoint[numOfPoints];
            for(int i = 0; i < numOfPoints; i++) {
                points[i] = new LocationPoint(locationsX[i], locationsY[i]);
                addActor(points[i]);
            }
        }

        batch  = GameUtils.batch;
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2, camera.viewportHeight/2, 0);
        camera.update();

        Music music = GameUtils.addMusic(anbientSound);
        music.setLooping(true);
        music.play();

        inputChain.addProcessor(this);
        inputChain.addProcessor(new GestureDetector(this));

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputChain);
    }


    public void draw() {

        Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl20.glClear(Gdx.gl20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        Batch batch = this.batch;
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();
        background.draw(batch);
        batch.end();

        batch.begin();

        for(int i = 0; i < numOfPoints; i++) {
            points[i].draw(batch, 1);
            addActor(points[i]);
        }

        batch.end();
    }


    public void dispose() {
        GameUtils.stopMusic();
        background.getTexture().dispose();
        anbientSound.dispose();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
    camera.translate(-deltaX, deltaY);

        float initialX = camera.viewportWidth / 2;
        float initialY = camera.viewportHeight / 2;

        GameUtils.limitBound(camera, initialX, initialY, background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
    camera.update();

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2, 
Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void pinchStop() {}

}
```

The method `activate()` is used to activate the resources of the Map class. The class Map also have a `ImageButtons` called `LocationPoints`.

```
public class LocationPoint extends ImageButton {

    private Monster monster;
    private Trap trap;
    public boolean occuped;
    public boolean isTrap;
    public int f = 20;
    public int k = 20;


    public LocationPoint(float x, float y) {
        super(GameUtils.getLocationDrawable());
        this.setSize(46, 46);
        setPosition(x, y);
        addListener(new InputListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                setPosition(f, k);
                f += 10;
                k += 10;
                return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
            }
        });
    }


    public void occup(Monster monster) {
        this.monster = monster;
        occuped = true;

        if(isTrap)
            captured();

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    }


    public void empty() {
        monster = null;
        occuped = false;
    }

    public void captured() {
        monster.capture();
    }


    public Monster getMonster() {
        return monster;
    }

}
```

In LocationPoint class I add a `InputListener` to make a thing when that LocationPoint is touched.
When a play the game on android both LocationPoints event and the Map `pan` event. But after I move the camera, when I touch on LocationPoint it don't fires that point event.

But when I return the camera to initial position the LocationPoints events works fine! Can you help me? (And sorry for my broken english...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Actor is already a child so remove redundant call from `draw()` method.

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < numOfPoints; i++) {
    points[i].draw(batch, 1);
    addActor(points[i]);             // <-- Not Should be in draw() call
  }
  ```
- Stage having own `SpriteBatch` that created by default constructor, use that one or pass own batch in `Stage` constructor.

  Use `getBatch()` method of `Stage` if you want to draw something by yourself.
- Creating camera in `Map` class also redundant, use `getViewport().getCamera()` that return camera of stage, you can typecast to `OrthographicCamera`
- call `super.dispose();` inside your `dispose()` method

---

Drawing all your Actor by yourself ? If you're not doing something beyond the scope, no need to override `draw()` method of `Stage`.

Comment: Thx, it works. I dunno that redundants code could be responsible.